# SonarQube coverage deviates of Jest coverage

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, sonarqube, code-coverage

I'm having hard time to understand why SonarQube has different coverage results compared to Jest coverage.

SQ coverage results[image: SQ coverage]

Jest coverage
[image: ![Jest coverage 3]

[image: Jest coverage 4]

[image: Jest coverage 1]

[image: Jest coverage 2]

My question is, why does the coverage deviate with a noticeable amount and how can you prevent this in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're talking about, for instance, the values of "82.4%" and "81.25%" (I think that's it, it's too small) for config.provider.ts, that's because SonarQube code coverage is actually a "weighted average" of multiple metrics.

Look at the details in this thread for the algorithm:
https://community.sonarsource.com/t/sonarqube-and-code-coverage/4725